# Servicenow - How to generate custom excel file from script

Tags: excel, servicenow, business-rules

I'm trying to generate a xls custom file through script and attach it to a record.

It works fine when I use csv extension but when I change into xls or xlsx the file will be corrupted once I downloaded it from attachment.

Is there any way to achieve this through script?

EDIT:
This is my sample script when I attach the file to a record:

`

```
var grRec = new GlideRecord("table"); 
grRec.addQuery("sys_id", sys_id); 
grRec.query(); 
if (grRec.next()) { 
var grAttachment = new GlideSysAttachment(); 
grAttachment.write(grRec, "test.xls", 'application/xls', xlsData); 
}
```

`

Comment: Is the download process damaging the file?

Comment: I don't think is the download process...probably is something on construction into the script.

When I attach the file to a record I do something like that:
`
var grRec = new GlideRecord("table");
  grRec.addQuery("sys_id", sys_id);
  grRec.query();
  if (grRec.next()) {
   var grAttachment = new GlideSysAttachment();
   grAttachment.write(grRec, "test.xls", 'application/xls', xlsData);
  } `